# Angular controllers in own files, undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm refactoring some angular code and I want to separate things by type (controllers in a controllers folder, etc.).

I have two controllers and an app.js file.  Why am I getting, and what does this undefined is not a function mean (I get an error in the console from both of my separate controller files)

```
app.js
var app = angular.module('myApp',['myApp.controllers']);

controllers
app.module('myApp.controllers').controller('DocumentController',function($scope){
    $scope.message = "This is the message from Document controller";
})
//
app.module('myApp.controllers').controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "This is the message from My Controller";
})

HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/MyController.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/DocumentController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    this is from the index.html page
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        {{message}}
    </div>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use angular.module instead of app.module. you app is an already defined module yu can not create a modle out of a module app.module==undefined

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I had tried that as well, that gives me an `Uncaught Object` error for both my controllers

Comment: do you need a new module for the controllers? If not can just use `app.controller(...` and skip the injection. Otherwise you need to create a module properly with dependencies argument

Comment: @charlietfl this is very much an exploratory phase for me.  I'm not sure that I need a different module for controllers, services etc.  But having everything in one giant file like I was doing is certainly not the way to go :)

Comment: what version of angular are you using? you might need to include ngRoute if you are using routes

Comment: generally don't need to create modules unless you want them to be portable to other projects. Modules that only contain controllers though aren't very practical, generally better to modularize functionality or features so a module would contain directives and services needed to compliment controlelrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the 'myApp.controllers' module before you can use it. To declare it you need to pass an array of dependencies into angular.module. Try changing app.js to this:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['myApp.controllers']);

var controllersApp = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

controllersApp.controller('DocumentController',function($scope){
    $scope.message = "This is the message from Document controller";
})

controllersApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "This is the message from My Controller";
})
```

Comment: swish, thanks.  what's your thought on the number of modules that you should have in an angular application, by the way?  I've heard conflicting reports on the number that should be used.

Comment: I put each controller into it's own file but add them all to the same module. If that module starts getting too big to maintain then I'd break it into smaller modules. You also sometimes need to make smaller modules when you want to test something like a controller without running your main apps config section. For really big apps I've head of people putting every controller, directive, service, etc. into it's own module but I wouldn't worry about doing that until a need arises